# How do I make cake batter from scratch without butter?

Tags: cake, batter, cupcakes

I need to make a cake, but I don't have butter, I could go buy some, but I don't have time because i need to do this cake right now and finish it in an hour so i can give it to someone.

Comment: Make a cake recipe that doesn't require butter: http://allrecipes.com/search/default.aspx?ms=0&origin=Home+Page&qt=i&wt=cake&pqt=i&fo=0&rt=r&u0=butter

Answer (score 2):

One option is an angel food cake, it's butter-free and doesn't require any other butter substitutes.  On the down side it will take a full hour to finish and another 45 minutes to be ready to eat...

[Basic Recipe](http://dairyfreecooking.about.com/od/cakes/r/Angel-Food-Cake.htm)